# How to configure Hibernate database reverse engineering tool to map database table relation as a entites inheritance?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, reverse-engineering

Is it possible to configure Hibernate reverse engineering and code generation tool in such a way that one-to-many relation between tables is mapped to entities inheritance instead of enrites relation?

I have Person table and Employee table, which are related with the foreign key (Person contains basic information, Employee the rest). In my Java code I would like this relation mapped to inheritance Employee extends Person.

This can be done by hand,  but maybe I missed some custom configuration parameter that I can use.

I couldn't find any official documentation - docs link on RedHat Hibernate page (http://www.hibernate.org/5.html#A10) is broken...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this (old) thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2368310), this is not possible (and this [more recent discussion](http://www.mail-archive.com/jboss-user@lists.jboss.org/msg148138.html) suggest it's still not).

You'll have to modify the relevant templates (not sure how you can you can use a custom template for some tables only).